Is there a finite upper bound for the minimal number of generators of finitely generated clones on a set with $3$ elements?
This is a natural follow-up to my previous universal algebra question, here: Is there a finite upper bound for the minimal number of generators of a Boolean clone?. Consider the set $\{0,1,2\}$, and consider the set $S$ of all clones over it. Now, some members of $S$ are not finitely generated, so just throw out the ones that are not, and get the subset $F$ of all finitely generated clones. Similar to my previous question, I want to know if there is a finite upper bound for the minimal number of generators of a clone in $F$. More specifically, let $\kappa$ be the least cardinal such that every clone in $F$ has a generating set with $\kappa$ or fewer elements. I want to know what the value of $\kappa$ is, if it is $\aleph_0$ or a finite number, and if the latter, exactly which finite number it is.

Here's a first guess: can you show that each $C_n=\langle{j_k: k\le n}\rangle$, where $j_k$ is as in this old answer of mine, is not generated by $n-1$ elements? (I'm not sure this is true, it just seems plausible.)
